# How to maintain record of my App's previous launch time

Tags: android

I want to restrict my app's launch based on the number
 of times the user has accessed my app in between a particular
 time interval. So I thought that if I know my app's previous
 launch, I could achieve it. If there is something else possible ,
 plz someone out there help me..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On your app launch, increment and store a variable in Shared Preferences. Check this at each start.

Comment: Can I get an example for that. Bcoz I am totally new to android

Comment: Anyway. Something is better than nothing. Thanks for your help man.

Comment: @Andro_Selva See the answer the this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861379/android-sharedpreferences

Comment: That was really helpful. I think that I have got what I needed. thanks.