# get the IMEI number of phone having the Android Version 8.1 as the telephonyManager.getDeviceId(); have being deprecated after Marshmallow

Tags: android, telephonymanager, android-8.0-oreo, imei, android-8.1-oreo

```
@SuppressLint({"MissingPermission", "NewApi"})
public void getDeviceIMEI() {
    String deviceUniqueIdentifier = null;
    String deviceImei = null;
    if (null != telephonyManager) {
        deviceUniqueIdentifier = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
        Log.d("Output_getDeviceIMEI", deviceUniqueIdentifier + "");
    }
//   

     if (null == deviceUniqueIdentifier || 0 == deviceUniqueIdentifier.length()) {
//            deviceUniqueIdentifier = Settings.Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
//            Log.d("Output_getDev_null", deviceUniqueIdentifier + "");
//        }

    if (null != telephonyManager) {
        if ( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT <= Build.VERSION_CODES.O_MR1 && Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
            deviceImei = telephonyManager.getImei();
            Log.d("Output_deviceImei_IMEI", deviceImei + "");
        }

    }
    if (null == deviceImei || 0 == deviceImei.length()) {
        deviceImei = Settings.Secure.getString(this.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.ANDROID_ID);
        Log.d("Output_deviceImei", deviceImei + "");
    }
```

}

Comment: my problem is  "telephonyManager.getDeviceId(); " this method which down't work after the marshmallow because when i write it, it ask for permission check for oreo which i have already given but even though I couldn't get IMEI number for android version 8.1.

Comment: " telephonyManager.getDeviceId();" my problem is this method which doesn't work after 6.0 & I want for 8.1 device version ie oreo

Comment: You are already using `deviceImei = telephonyManager.getImei();` still it doesn't work?

Comment: please visit this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46744104/tm-getdeviceid-is-deprecated), it is relevant to your problem.

Comment: Your if condition is wrong try this `if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){deviceImei = telephonyManager.getImei();}else{deviceImei =telephonyMgr.getDeviceId();}`

Comment: @ Ikram Hussain - I coldn't get the relevant data please share the exact url

Comment: @ Sagar  - thq for ur reply but the log is below             
D/Output_getDev_null: e91010813f0dbf19

Comment: @SUNIL - here is my code please inform me where I am wrong

Comment: @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);
       
        getDeviceIMEI(); }

Comment: @SUNIL - @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    public void getDeviceIMEI() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            deviceImei = telephonyManager.getImei();
            Log.d("Output_getDev_null", deviceImei + "");
        } else {
            deviceImei = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
            Log.d("Output_getDev", deviceImei + "");
        }
    }

Comment: @SAGAR - @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    public void getDeviceIMEI() {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            deviceImei = telephonyManager.getImei();
            Log.d("Output_getDev_null", deviceImei + "");
        } else {
            deviceImei = telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
            Log.d("Output_getDev", deviceImei + "");
        }
    }

Comment: @PriyankaYadav check the updated answer

Comment: thq very much Sagar for your kind help

Comment: @Sagar - please check this

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50603883/in-google-play-console-panel-apk-is-in-alpha-version-not-yet-public

Comment: @sagar hey please see my query on maps Required ur guidance

Comment: @sagar Yes I have

Comment: @Sagar - Send Email in background without user interface in Android programmatically
 plx check and reskm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from android 8 you need to use [getImei(int slotIndex)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getimei) to retrieve the IMEI of the device.

You also need to add `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>` permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml`

Remember to implement permission model to request permission at runtime as follows:

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE},
                    1);
@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode,
                                       String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1: {

          // If request is cancelled, the result arrays are empty.
          if (grantResults.length > 0
                    && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

               //continue using `getImei()` or `getDeviceId()`  
            } else {

               //Use device Id or use fallback case
            }
            return;
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: THank YOU Very Much SAGAR for your help

Comment: Thank you for this! 
I can confirm that it works on Android 9.1 !!!