# In google play console panel APK, is in ALPHA Version not yet public

Tags: android, api, google-maps, android-studio, location

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <manifest                        
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
        <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
        <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
        <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
        <uses-permission
        android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_MULTICAST_STATE" 
        />
        <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS" />
        <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
        <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
        <uses-permission
            android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
        <uses-permission
            android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
        <uses-permission 
        android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
        <uses-permission
            android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
        <application
            android:allowBackup="true"
            android:icon="@drawable/app_icon_xhdpi"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:logo="@drawable/app_icon_xhdpi"
            android:supportsRtl="true"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

            <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
                android:value="<MAP API KEY>"/>
            <activity
                android:name=".MapsActivity"
                android:label="@string/title_activity_maps">
            </activity>
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

In google play console panel APK, is in ALPHA Version not yet public, In alpha I can download the apk so in it, Map is appearing But where as the apk downloaded from google play store Map doesn't appear ???? The keystore path and all keystore setting are correct. In Manifest file the API key of MAP have taken from Console Developer. SHA is correctly generated and placed.

Comment: Do you really share your API_KEY ?

Comment: while doing build apk --> build variant I have changed to release option, but release folder is not automatically created in Project folder.

Comment: I mean you should not paste your API_KEY on a public website, no ?

Comment: As I know for debug apk also -->A debug folder will be created inside the project --> res --> value --> debug-map-apk.xml  file but where as for release it wan't created ?? Can any 1 tell me what might be the reason ???

Comment: @yunandtidus For testing the apk I have kept in APLHA version and have not release to production.

Comment: Since you registered for Alpha version, you wont be able to use it in release version. Generate another key for release.

Comment: @sagar - So with the new API key I have to sign the app again --> generate a new apk and move it to production from release

Comment: @sagar -- Do u means the above answere of mine ?

Comment: Yes. Read the documentation before doing that. Configure API key, Signature and follow all the steps. Before uploading to Play store, remember to test locally

Comment: @sagar  thq sagar but i have already gone through dem

Comment: @sagar - whnen i download APK from play store nw after changes map is still not appearing

Comment: @sagar - I have run "Download derived APK"  from production dat also doen't display's the map where as the original APK have the map in google play console ???

Comment: @PriyankaYadav You mean, if you build app with release version it works, but if you download the same app from play store it doesn't?

Comment: @sagar Yes you can download and check from google play store app name is Smart parking Zone, click on button u will reach navigation

Comment: @sagar send me your mail id so that I can send u release apk ?? Can I

Comment: @PriyankaYadav then no idea why its not working. Just ensure you have proper internet connection

Comment: @sagar okay thq for help