# Serial number or IMEI got changed in android

Tags: android, samsung-mobile, imei, google-pixel

We are using the Serial number and IMEI in an application and we have observed that there are many Pixel, Samsung and Motorola devices where either the serial number or IMEI has been changed.

What could be reason ?

1. Due to OS update ?
2. Access this data in background ?
3. Manufacturer defect
4. Fetching these details during OS update process ?
5. Could be possible some time, but in next re-try will get correct one ?

*Note:* We have observed this only in Android OS Version 7,8,9. We are using

For IMEI:

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager = (TelephonyManager) mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
imei= telephonyManager.getDeviceId();
```

For serial number:

```
Build.SERIAL
```

Comment: `getDeviceId` is deprecated, probably that is the reason it mayu work incorrecnty

Comment: I have more than 50devices with me, I do use of IMEI of those phones but never get changed,
But if you factory reset or update your device then you Serial Number may change

Comment: **[tm.getDeviceId() is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46744104/tm-getdeviceid-is-deprecated/46744134#46744134)**

Comment: `Build.SERIAL` is also deprecated, and will return some default value starting from Android O.

Comment: I honestly thought everyone had already switched to [advertiser Ids](http://www.androiddocs.com/google/play-services/id.html)