# Get DeviceId Depricated Android

Tags: android, deprecated

[Android Developer Device ID Depricated](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html#getDeviceId())

**Android has changed the `getDeviceID()` it says to use @link getMeid which user READ_PHONE_STATE permission where the security level of this permission is Dangerous**

As the permission level is dangerous i m looking for any alternate way to Get IMEI Number.

I tried using `getUniqueid()` but it is generating a unique number each time.

Kindly let me know any alternate way to maintain device singularity. Thanks in Advance.

Comment: check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/46744134/7666442

Comment: What are you actually using it for?  Its highly unlikely you actually want the IMEI-  for one thing not all devices have one (any wireless only tablet will not, for example).  If you just want a unique id, check out https://developer.android.com/training/articles/user-data-ids

Answer (score 0):

Returns the unique device ID of a subscription, for example, the IMEI for GSM and the MEID for CDMA phones. Return null if device ID is not available.

This method was deprecated in API level 26.

Use (@link getImei} which returns IMEI for GSM

or (@link getMeid} which returns MEID for CDMA.

Try this to get IMEI

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            String imei = telephonyMgr.getImei();
} else {
            String imei = telephonyMgr.getDeviceId();
}
```

Comment: You just copied from google, I can get the IMEI as above even . But it asks for READ_PHONE_STATE permission. and the security level for READ_PHONE_STATE is dangerous, so i don't want to include it.

Comment: why don't you try for mac id

Comment: that's not perfect beacuse the user may change his device SIM and still we get the Same MAC ID