# How to get IMEI of the device in Android Q Beta?

Tags: android

I am trying `TelephonyService` `getDeviceId` but it is always giving me `null`.

Is there any other way around to get IMEI of the device.

I saw this post [tm-getdeviceid-is-deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46744104/tm-getdeviceid-is-deprecated), but `getMeid()`, `getImei()` both are are also returning `null`.

Comment: read this one https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/checklist