# java.lang.SecurityException android.telephony.TelephonyManager.getDeviceId

Tags: android

Below are my code getting security exception from Android version 7 and onwards. I have added `android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE` permission in manifest file and also added in runtime permissions also.

```java
TelephonyManager tManager = (TelephonyManager) context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);

String imeiNum= tManager.getDeviceId();
```

Comment: Can you add logs?

Comment: Check this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46744104/tm-getdeviceid-is-deprecated/46744134#46744134

Answer (score 0):

You're targeting api level 29. Since 29, it [throws a SecurityException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager#getDeviceId(int)) .
`getDeviceId()` is deprecated since API 26, you should try `getImei()` ;

Answer (score -1):

If you want to get imei, you can try

```
TelephonyManager tm = (TelephonyManager) getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    String imei = tm.getImei();
} else {
    String imei = tm.getDeviceId();
}
```